# ¿Cómo recorrer un objeto en Javascript de manera asociativa para obtener sus datos?

Tags: javascript, json, array, objeto

Tengo el siguiente objeto:

```
var mData = [];
```

Le asigno datos de manera dinámica:

```
mData.push({ Fila1: { Dato1: "Dato1", Dato2: "Dato2" } });
mData.push({ Fila2: { Dato3: "Dato3", Dato4: "Dato4" } });
```

Mi duda surge en como recorrer Fila por fila del `mData` y a su vez recorrer los datos que se encuentren en la fila.

**Ejemplo:**

```
mData["Fila1"]["Dato1"]..["Fila1"]["DatoN"]
mData["Fila2"]["Dato3"]..["Fila1"]["DatoN"]
```

Es esencial que sea asociativo para los fines que busco.

Comment: Puedes construir tu objeto como quieras, a condición de que produzca un JSON válido, luego: 1. Lo pasas al servidor usando `JSON.stringify()`; 2º. Lo recuperas en el servidor usando `json_decode`; 3º. Lo lees según la estructura que tenga. Para fines de verificación/recuperación en el `$_POST` puedes ponerle una clave por fuera al objeto global, algo así como `allData`, y luego en `$_POST['allData']` estará tu objeto.

Comment: Creo que donde tengo un bloqueo, es para identificar la fila (anidar), que sería `Filtro1:{Datos de busqueda} ` creo que mi problema surge en agregar un JSON dentro de un JSON en el array, espero explicarme. Solo es con el fin de obtener el nombre asociado de la fila y acceder a los datos luego (todos tienen el mismo nombre)

Comment: No sé si te refieres a algo como esto: `{ "Filtro1": {"nombre":"1Nombre", "apellido":"1Apellido"}, "Filtro2": {"nombre":"2Nombre","apellido":"2Apellido"}, "Filtro3": {"nombre":"3Nombre","apellido":"3Apellido"} }`, ahí cada nodo tiene su identificador: `Filtro1, Filtro2, Filtro3` y podrás acceder a c/uno de forma nominal para obtener luego los datos que haya en `nombre` y `apellido`. OJO, esta es una estructura fija, que sólo conviene si te interesa verificar u obtener datos mediante propiedades fijas. Si por el contrario te interesa leer todo sin interesar la propiedad, lo suyo sería un array.

Comment: Entre la estructura y esta: `{"Filtros":[ {"nombre":"1Nombre","apellido":"1Apellido"}, {"nombre":"2Nombre","apellido":"2Apellido"},{"nombre":"3Nombre","apellido":"3Apellido"} ]}`hay una diferencia enorme en cuanto al uso y forma de leer los datos. Aquí tenemos un array de objetos JSON que está dentro de `Filtros`, recorriendo el array podrás obtener cada `nombre` y `apellido` sin tener que referir a la propiedad que lo contiene, como ocurre en la estructura anterior. Lo importante es entender que son dos formas distintas de organizar datos, dependiendo del tipo de lectura que requieras.

Comment: Por ejemplo tengo declarado mi array `var array = [] ` que tengo que hacer para agregar el primer valor `{Filtro1:{Datos} } `?

Comment: Creo que lo expliqué en el primer comentario. Puedes construir tu estructura como la necesites y usando lo que tengas a mano, eso es lo de menos. La cosa es que crearías una variable con un contenido así más o menos: `var mData='{ "Filtro1": {"nombre":"1Nombre", "apellido":"1Apellido"}, "Filtro2": {"nombre":"2Nombre","apellido":"2Apellido"}, "Filtro3": {"nombre":"3Nombre","apellido":"3Apellido"} }';`  y luego `var toPost=JSON.stringify(mData);` y luego pasas `toPost` al servidor. Finalmente, la lectura en el servidor dependerá de qué estructura sea.

Comment: Puedes crear `mData` a mano, o juntando objetos, o leyendo elementos del DOM o como quieras, eso depende de lo que tengas a mano. O puedes generar el JSON de forma automática con alguna herramienta. Igualmente, puedes darle la estructura que más te convenga, según la lógica que estés implementando.

Comment: @A.Cedano hice un replanteamiento de la pregunta agregando código

Answer (score 1):

Puedes iterar los elementos de un objeto en JS usando `Object.keys(objeto)`. Por ejemplo:

```javascript
for (const data of mData) {                 // Iterar un Array
  for (const linea of Object.keys(data)) {  // Iterar el Array de keys presentes en un objeto
    console.log(`Clave: ${linea}`);
    console.log(`Valor: ${ JSON.styringify(data[linea]) }`);

    // Con los datos de la pregunta, para la primera
    // vuelta de ambos bucles, la salida sería:
    //   Clave: Fila1
    //   Valor: {"Dato1":"Dato1","Dato2":"Dato2"}
  }
}
```

A parte de esto, cabe recalcar que todo depende de qué quieras hacer con estos datos. Por ejemplo, si la intención es crear un objeto nuevo, probablemente prefieras usar `map`/`reduce`. Con la información que das, no se puede concretar mucho más.

#### Editado

También puedes usar `for (... in ...) {}` :

```javascript
for (const data of mData) {    // Iterar un Array
  for (const linea in data) {  // Iterar las keys presentes en un objeto
    console.log(`Clave: ${linea}`);
    console.log(`Valor: ${ JSON.styringify(data[linea]) }`);

    // Con los datos de la pregunta, para la primera
    // vuelta de ambos bucles, la salida sería:
    //   Clave: Fila1
    //   Valor: {"Dato1":"Dato1","Dato2":"Dato2"}
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

El problema principal que veo en tu código es que **estás creando un objeto complicado e irregular**, y eso va a dificultar su lectura *a posteriori*.

Primero veamos una forma de leer tu objeto. Aquí suponemos que interesa mostrar cada dato al lado de su clave correspondiente.

Vamos a dejar el objeto preparado de entrada, aplicando `JSON.parse()` a lo que obtengamos con `JSON.stringify()`. Luego habrá que ir accediendo a los diferentes niveles del objeto hasta llegar a cada JSON que haya dentro de `Fila1`, `Fila2`, etc. Usaré tres `for` del mismo tipo sin entrar en funciones complicadas que podrían facilitar el trabajo. Mi intuición aquí es que podrías repensar tu forma de organizar el objeto como veremos al final.

```js
var mData = [];

mData.push({
  Fila1: {
    Dato1: "VDato1",
    Dato2: "VDato2"
  }
});
mData.push({
  Fila2: {
    Dato3: "VDato3",
    Dato4: "VDato4"
  }
});

var mJson = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(mData));

/*Índices: 0, 1, etc*/
for (const i in mJson) {
  /*Filas*/
  for (const fila in mJson[i]) {
    console.log(`${fila}:`);
    /*Cada item particular*/
    for( key in mJson[i][fila]) {
        console.log(`\t${key}: ${mJson[i][fila][key]}`);
    }
  }
}
```

### Recomendación

Como decía al principio. Considera las siguientes recomendaciones:

1. No des nombres de propiedades distintas a tus objetos anidados. JSON es un modelo estructurado, que serviría por ejemplo para organizar datos provenientes de una tabla, donde las columnas se llaman igual. Esto simplificaría el código y obtener cualquier dato en particular sabiendo de antemano que las propiedades se llaman siempre igual. Si las propiedades cambian cada vez, esto puede complicarte la vida en algunos escenarios.
2. Podrías prescindir de las propiedades `Filas...`, si estas son secuenciales. Por el mismo motivo, JSON es un formato de dato estructurado. Si quisieras saber en qué fila estás, para eso estaría el índice (sería la variable `i` del primer `for` más arriba), con ese dato ya sabes si es la primera fila, la segunda, etc. Tu estructura inicial sólo se justificaría cuando quieres mandar datos irregulares en un JSON. Si los datos son los mismos, simplifica mucho el trabajo mandar un array de objetos todos identificados con la misma clave.

Veamos un ejemplo. El código es simple cuando las propiedades se llaman siempre igual y quieres acceder directamente a los valores:

```js
var mData = [];

    mData.push(
       {
        Dato1: "VDato1",
        Dato2: "VDato2"
      }
    );
    mData.push({
        Dato1: "VDato3",
        Dato2: "VDato4"
      }
    );

var mJson = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(mData));

for(const i in mJson){
  console.log(`Fila${i}`); 
  for (const k in mJson[i]){
    console.log(`\t${k}: ${mJson[i][k]}`);
  }
}
```

O, supongamos que se te pide obtener las claves ya conocidas de antemano. El código se hace más simple todavía. Esto es lo que significa que JSON es estructurado. Esto es muy útil cuando necesitas datos en secuencia, mediante prpopiedades determinadas. Si observas, aquí se usa un sólo bucle, porque ya conoces las claves de antemano.

```js
var mData = [];

mData.push({
  Dato1: "VDato1",
  Dato2: "VDato2"
});
mData.push({
  Dato1: "VDato3",
  Dato2: "VDato4"
});

var mJson = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(mData));

for (const i in mJson) {
  console.log(`Fila${i}`);
  console.log(`\tDato1: ${mJson[i].Dato1}\n\tDato2: ${mJson[i].Dato2}`);
}
```

Comment: ¿Qué puedo hacer para crear, editar o eliminar un elemento en particular? Es decir, implemento el problema para almacenar información de datos para búsquedas en consultas `SQL` (Es la única forma que se me ocurrio) por eso pretendo que sea asociativo a según del filtro que sea y con el fin de manipular los datos del mismo, por eso decía que como puedo obtener la fila en la que estoy, por ejemplo `Nombre:{....}`

Comment: @FernyCortez en ese caso sí es mejor que organices cada objeto con su nombre de clave, **porque conocerías de antemano lo que se va a buscar**, así, si lo que interesa es verificar que `Filtro1` u otro valor existen en el json verificarlas eso directamente, mi recomendación es el caso de necesitar recorrer un grupo de objetos para sacar su información. Son dos cosas diferentes. Un json lo estructuras del modo que sea más conveniente, según el uso que quieras darle.